# Pillow doesn't show installation summary

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In my Django project I've got an Error: decoder jpeg not available

So I googled it and tried a few things. Now I have installed Pillow, but at the end there was no Installation summary.

In this summary, I could see if JPEG support is available (installed jpeg library before).

Comment: How have you installed Pillow? Pip or easy_install? Try `pip upgrade`

Comment: it was pip, I tried pip upgrade, but it says 'ERROR: unknown command "upgrade"'. I'm working on Mac Mavericks btw

Comment: Sorry: `pip install -U`

Comment: Did it, but it's up-to-date

Comment: Then try to uninstall and the reinstall it

Comment: `sudo pip unintall Pillow`, then installed it again but output is just `Successfully installed Pillow` and Error is still there